# How can I switch user in a shell and use the existing gnome display session?

Tags: command-line, xorg, display

If I switch user in a terminal.

`su bob`

I can't open `gedit` because `bob` doesn't own the display.

If I execute

`xhost +`

before switching to `bob` I can open the display for some applications but not all.  I get the following output when trying to execute `gedit`:

> (crashreporter:4415): GnomeUI-WARNING
>   **: While connecting to session manager: None of the authentication
>   protocols specified are supported.
>
>   ** GLib-GIO:ERROR:/build/buildd/glib2.0-2.28.6/./gio/gdbusconnection.c:2279:initable_init:
>   assertion failed:
>   (connection->initialization_error ==
>   NULL)

Comment: Try command line editors like `nano`.

Comment: @Oxwivi Sure, and I do use `nano` a lot but in this case `gedit` is just one of the GUI applications I wasn't able to open.

Comment: The only program you can't open as another user? You should include it in the question.

Comment: Try to avoid `xhost +` if you're on a networked computer, as that disables X security and gives anyone on the network permission to connect to your X display and do things like reading your keyboard from remote...

Comment: @Oxwivi It could also be `firefox`, that doesn't work either, it's just in general, I want to be able to do this.  `gedit` was a poor example, you are right about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow user `bob` to access your existing X session from
the command line, you can enter these commands at the terminal prompt:

```
xauth nextract - $DISPLAY | sudo -u bob xauth nmerge -
```

Thius uses the [xauth](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xauth) command to
extract the authentication information for the current user (first
part of the command, before the `|`) and then merge it into user
`bob`'s `$HOME/.Xauthority` file.  Note that it requires
`/etc/sudoers` to be configured so that you are allowed to run
commands as user `bob` (this is the default if you're the admin user
on a Ubuntu box).

You can then switch to user `bob` with `su -l`.

Alternatively, you can issue these separate commands:

```
xauth nextract - $DISPLAY > /tmp/xauth.temporary.file
su -l bob -c 'xauth nmerge - < /tmp/xauth.temporary.file'
rm /tmp/xauth.temporary.file
```

Note that:

1) the temporary file must have permissions such that user `bob` can
     read it (which often means that *any* user on the system can read
     it);

2) there is a time window during which any user that can read the
     temporary file can get access to your X display.

Therefore, it is better to use the `sudo` approach as it does not have
these downsides.

Comment: I got this to work, but: *su: must be run from a terminal*

Comment: @z7sg: Yes, of course it must be run in a terminal.  Isn't that what your question is about?  How to switch to another user in a terminal and still be able to launch X applications from that same terminal?

Comment: @Ricardo Yes, but `su` doesn't like being run from a pipe.  It's a security issue.

Comment: @z7sg Oh, I see. You're right, but you can use `sudo` instead of `su` and not run into this problem. I'll edit my answer with details.

Comment: From my desktop running xubuntu, I run ssh -X otherhost. From that host, DISPLAY is "localhost:10.0". When I try xauth extract - $DISPLAY I get an error, No matches found, authority file "-" not written

Comment: @djb You should not need to do any `xauth` magic: `ssh` already handles the details for you.

Comment: Thanks, @RiccardoMurri - I left out something. From my desktop, I ssh -X somehost to login as myself and X works. From there, I want to sudo and have that command use my desktop display. But after doing ssh -X, the remote shell has DISPLAY set to a local proxy (localhost:10.0 for example) and this can't be passed to sudu (or other su userid commands). The pipeline above fails because localhost is not known to xauth. But this works: [[ xauth nextract - ${DISPLAY/localhost/$(hostname)/unix} | sudo xauth nmerge - ]] followed by sudo xcommand . I must change localhost to $(hostname)/unix for xauth

Answer (score 0):

Another way, after `xhost +` has been executed:

```
dbus-launch gedit --sm-client-disable
```